# How update a value of a HashMap that is an object?

Tags: java, hashmap

If the value is a class called Hand

```
public class Hand implements Iterable<Card>{
    protected List<Card> cards;
    .....
    .....
}
```

and my HashMap is

```
HashMap<Integer, Hand> hashMap;
```

If I want to add a Card object to the instance field of `Hand` i.e `cards`, do I need to do

```
hashMap.get(i).cards.add(Card Object)
```

or do I need to do

```
hashMap.put(i, hashMap.get(i).cards.add(Card Object))
```

Comment: Did you try both options to see what happens?

Comment: `add(Card Object)` won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `Hand` instance already exists, you would want to retrieve the instance:

```
Hand hand = hashMap.get(i);
```

Once you have the instance, you want to access its `cards` list and add another card to it:

```
Card card = ...;
hand.cards.add(card); //consider using a getMethod to get the cards
```

Or in your own code:

```
hashMap.get(i).cards.add(card);
```

You don't need to remap the hand element in the hashmap because you aren't replacing the actual `Hand` object, so the reference to it in the map remains the same. All you are doing is modifying one of its properties by adding an item in the `Hands`'s cards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter for `cards` within `Hand` class like

```
protected List<Card> getCards() {
    return this.cards;
}
```

and then update as follows -

```
hashMap.get(i).getCards().add(new Card())
```

---

Attempting

```
hashMap.put(i, hashMap.get(i).getCards().add(new Card()))
```

is trying to put a `boolean` returned from `add` at index `i` instead and wouldn't work good with your logic.